# Spring Batch distorts number 2,981.00 to 2-981.00

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I am trying to load a file into batch. The file looks correct. The value is 2,981.00. but somewhere during processing the value changes to 2-981.00. Spring batch also downloads file as json . Even the json file looks correct . But when the file gets written into db, the value changes to 2-981.00. I get the following exception. Any suggestions please? Thanks!

Caused by: org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
Field error in object 'target' on field 'temp': rejected value [2-981.00]; codes [typeMismatch.target.temp,typeMismatch.temp,typeMismatch.java.math.BigDecimal,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [target.temp,temp]; arguments []; default message [temp]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.math.BigDecimal' for property 'temp'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException]

Comment: share the code to load the file

Comment: Changing the datatype in the bean (Entity model) resolved the issue. Changed from number to string